# node js - get url params from original base url

Tags: node.js, express

In my node JS express app I have defined routes with path having regex expressions in my app.js file. i.e

```
var tableRoute = require('./routes/tables');
app.use('/keyspaces/(regex to match param)/tables',tableRoute);
```

Then in my routes/tables.js file I have following handler defined for this route

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
// need to access url param here
});
```

Now clearly I cannot access my url param via req.params.xzy because here handler is defined for '/' not for '/keyspaces/:xzy/tables', is there any way I can access this url param here from original base url.

Comment: You could probably add a header to the `req` in the `tableRoute` handler. Then read the header in your `/` handler.

Comment: @Tony thanks for your response but this workaround doesn't sound like a clean approach. This way I could also access base url by req.baseUrl property and extract param. I am just looking for proper api call or better approach to handle these kind of situations.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski app.use() only take regex, it gives you error if you do something like this 'app.use('/keyspaces/:xyz/tables', tableRoute);'

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with modifying the request as you forward it. Doesn't even have to be a header, just add a property to `req`. It seems less clear to me to forward the route. Why not just use `router.get('/keyspaces..., tableRoute)` so you can use `req.params.xyz`? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: @Tony because I need to handle requests going to '/keyspaces' and '/keyspaces/xzy/tables' in different modules.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a middleware to handle it.
In your example :

```
var tableRoute = require('./routes/tables');
app.use('/keyspaces/:xzy/tables',function(req,res,next){
  req.xyz=req.params.xyz;
  next();
},tableRoute);
```

Then in routes table you can access it and set req.params by your own :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  req.params.xyz = req.xyz;
});
```

Comment: as mentioned below you need to add next() in the middleware! (just edited it for you)

Answer (score 0):

refer to this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment).

for me its work only with call to the next middleware,
else he will end in the first middleware call

like this:

```
var tableRoute = require('./routes/tables');
app.use('/keyspaces/:xzy/tables',function(req,res,next){
    req.xyz=req.params.xyz;
    next();
},tableRoute);
```

and then you can add:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   req.params.xyz = req.xyz;
});
```