# Handling different routes that start similarly in NodeJS, Express

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm creating an API which have Articles and Comments belonging to those articles.

```
const articleRoutes = require('./api/routes/articles');
const commentRoutes = require('./api/routes/comments');
```

then

```js
app.use('/articles', articleRoutes);
app.use('/comments', commentRoutes);
```

Anything starting with "articles/" gets forwarded to articleRoutes, and anything starting with "comments/" gets forwarded to commentRoutes.
Comment GET requests are like

```
/comments?article=ID_OF_ARTICLE
```

Like this everything is working perfectly.

However
I want to restructure the comments route to be like

```
/articles/ID_OF_ARTICLE/comments
```

However now they both start with "/articles"

How would I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
app.use('/articles/:id/comments', commentRoutes);
app.use('/articles', articleRoutes);
```

So I think the order is important in the above.

```
// inside commentRoutes
Router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let articlesId = req.originalUrl.split('/')[2]
})
```

I hope this helps

Comment: But honestly I would just use it inside the /comments like router.get('/:articleid')

Comment: Would that work? when I do app.use('/articles/:id/comments', commentRoutes); wouldn't the :id be lost? would I be able to access it in route.get('/') in commentRoutes?

Comment: You need to do a bit of a workaround, but it could work. Instead of using req.params, you need to parse it from req.originalUrl which should return /articles/theIdYouWant/comments

Answer (score 1):

The originalUrl approach seems to work too, But I went with the solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37157070/6493611)

Apparently I can do

```js
app.use('/articles/:articleId/comments', function(req, res, next) {
    req.articleId = req.params.articleId;
    next();
}, commentRoutes);
```

and in commentRoutes

```js
// in commentRoutes
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    let articleId = req.articleId
})
```

So I can attach the required parameter to the request as a separate entry and access it directly